# How to open a pop up window using javascript/Jquery for firefox browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to open a pop up window using javascript/Jquery for firefox browser?it is working in other browsers except firefox.

```
  <xsl:if test="$ShowRejectLink='Yes'">
           xsl:if test='$RejectLink!=""'>      
    <a href="{$RejectLink}" target="_new">Reject</a>
```

If i click this link means.it will open the pop up window

http://localhost:6060/jsp/rejectPopup.jsp?id=166899&responseStatusId=2&ApprovalFlag=true

Comment: try target="_newtab"... it will work...

Comment: just want to give u one small advice give live link not your localhost  link

Answer (score 0):

Use target = "_blank". Should do the trick. But if you want a real pop up you should create a new window.

Use this... I can't make it simpler than that: http://javascriptsource.com/generators/popup-window.html